# Customize mouseover hover of a bubble in Googlevis bubblechart

Tags: r, googlevis, bubble-chart

How to remove the axis labels from the label on the bubble in the Googlevis Bubblechart that comes on hovering

[image: screenshot]

Basically I want to remove the features like x, y and size that come once you hover over a bubble

Comment: use `hovervar= ` in your code

Comment: Could you possibly give an example..i'm new to this and am not so sure of the syntax

Comment: bub <- gvisBubbleChart(
        temp33, idvar = "ID",
        xvar = "x", yvar = "y",
        colorvar = "color",sizevar = "size",
        options = list(
          width = 800, height = 600,bubble.textStyle = '{fontSize : 1}',
          vAxis = "{title:'Low Risk Region...................High Risk Region'}",
          colors = "['#58FA82','#FE642E', '#819FF7']"
        )
      )

Comment: Try `bub <- gvisBubbleChart( temp33, idvar = "ID", hovervar="x", xvar = "x", yvar = "y", colorvar = "color",sizevar = "size", options = list( width = 800, height = 600,bubble.textStyle = '{fontSize : 1}', vAxis = "{title:'Low Risk Region...................High Risk Region'}", colors = "['#58FA82','#FE642E', '#819FF7']" ) ) `

Comment: If the above doesnt work then Im afraid there is no way to do it.

Comment: This is not working
It throws the error 
unused argument (hovervar = "x")

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart. There is no hover option for bubble charts. Write to the developer and ask him to update his package.